# how to have make a QString have a specific size in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

My problem is that in i will have a `QString val`that will get different values there. But i want all of results to have a fixed number of charaters, for example 20.

So if the word i put there is less than that number of charaters it will put white spaces to the right.

An example, lets suppose i have 2 words: `"abc"` and `"abcdefghijklmno"`

for the `first case`:

`qDebug()<<val; //"abc                 "`

for the `second case`:

`qDebug()<<val; //"abcdefghijklmno     "`

how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following approach

```
qDebug() << QString("%1").arg(yourStringVar, fieldWidth, QChar('fillEmptySpaceChar'));
```

in your example it could be

```
qDebug() << QString("%1").arg(val, 32, QChar(' '));
```

for making fill characters to fill from right simply use following

```
qDebug() << QString("%1").arg(val, -32, QChar(' '));
```

Comment: Awesome, but how can the space be added to the right instead?

Comment: use negative `fieldWidth` instead

Answer (score 3):

Use can use `QString::resize`. It takes the size and a fill character:

```
val.resize(20,' ');
qDebug() << val;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you use the functions [`QString::leftJustified()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#leftJustified) / `QString::rightJustified()` created specifically for this purpose :

```
qDebug() << val.leftJustified(20, /*QChar fill=*/QLatin1Char(' '), /*bool truncate=*/false);
```

This also lets you choose how to proceed if your input string is longer than your fixed width.